# Need to display three different message once i have submit single form

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

i have a servlet and a form which call the servlet when i give sumbit inside the servelt i have three different operation taking place. i need to display a message like ("XXXX" processing) for each operation is it possible to send three different message from servlet to jsp in single form submit request

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using ajax .

You have to write some thing like a timed request on your jsp to invoke a separate request to check the status of the submit action.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.get("checkStatus",function(response){
       //update the message
    });
}, 3000);
```

Put the above code inside a while loop. Make sure that the loop starts only once you clicked the submit button.

Since the ajax requests are asynchronous the loop will not wait for the request to finish so make sure to provide enough timeout.

Once the processing is done break out of the loop by changing.

The status check response I use json so that I can send more information like status of the action and the message or any other data you want to pass.

Complete code :

```
var isLopp = true;
$("submitButton").on("click", function() {
    $(this).attr("disable", true);
    while (isLopp) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("checkStatus", function(resp) {
                if(resp.status="done"){
                    isLopp=false;
                }
                $("message").text(resp.msg);
            },"json");
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Instead if while loop you can also use `window.setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);`

for more details : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp